# Regex match text with delimiters in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I have a text with this structure:

```
Text Starts
23/01/2018
Something here. It was a crazy day.
Believe me.
02/02/2018
Another thing happens.
Some Delimiter
20/02/2017
Text here
21/02/2017
Another text.
Here.
End Section
...text continues...
```

And a regex with to match group of (date, text) until `Some Delimiter` in python:

```
result = re.findall(r"(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\n)(.*?)(?=\n\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}|\nSome Delimiter)", text, re.DOTALL)
```

Which results in:

```
>>> print(result)
[('23/01/2018\n', 'Something here. It was a crazy day. \nBelieve me.'),
('02/02/2018\n', 'Another thing happens.'),
('20/02/2017\n', 'Text here')]
```

It gets the next group after delimiter.

How can I get all groups before the delimiter?

Comment: Your regex returnes multiple matches. Do you want only one match? The one before the delimiter?

Comment: Try [`(?m)^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\n(.*?)(?=\n\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$|\nSome Delimiter|\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/07Wwmw/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it not works.

Comment: [Looke here](https://ideone.com/UFfI0V).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> print(text.split('Some Delimiter')[0])
Text Starts
23/01/2018
Something here. It was a crazy day.
Believe me.
02/02/2018
Another thing happens.

>>> re.findall(r"(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\n)(.*?)(?=\n\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}|$)", text.split('Some Delimiter')[0], re.DOTALL)
[('23/01/2018\n', 'Something here. It was a crazy day.\nBelieve me.'), ('02/02/2018\n', 'Another thing happens.')]
```

- `text.split('Some Delimiter')[0]` will give string before the delimiter
- then extract things on this portion alone

with [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r"(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\n)(.*?)(?=\n(?1)|$)", text.split('Some Delimiter')[0], re.DOTALL)
[('23/01/2018\n', 'Something here. It was a crazy day.\nBelieve me.'), ('02/02/2018\n', 'Another thing happens.')]
```

- `(?1)` will be same as the first group regex

Comment: do you think that is possible to resolve it with just regex?

Comment: try `r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\n(.*?)(?=\n(?:\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})?.*?Some Delimiter)'`